# how to align the textviews vertically in xml?

Tags: android, xml

I wrote a simple Android application. The problem is I don't know how to align the textviews vertically. (I have two textviews).

This is my snapshot of [xml layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyKmr.png) but I want my application to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bP3W.jpg) and this is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/fc"
        android:textSize="55dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="2.0" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/oc"
        android:textSize="55dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the second textview to be on top and the first textview lower.

Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `LinearLayout`s are horizontal by default. Add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the opening tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `android:orientation="vertical"` attribute in your `LinearLayout`. I think it is horizontal by default.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/fc"
    android:textSize="55dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2.0" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/oc"
    android:textSize="55dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

you needed to set

`android:orientation="vertical"`

and adding

`android:textAlignment="center"`

would align the text to center